# Javascript-based terminal emulator, SSH or similar

Tags: javascript, terminal

I'm looking for a way to make users interact with a Amazon EC2 instance, or any other machine, through an SSH terminal emulator or something similar from their browsers. Are there any libraries out there to allow such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Terminal](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/)

But you will need server-side script also, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Check out "[Secure Shell](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo)":

Only works for chrome